# Launch IOS application in Appium from terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, appium

I have to launch my IOS application in simulator from terminal through Appium. Is there some way I can do that. Making it more specific I want to perform the same action which the launch button in following image perform from terminal

[image: Appium interface]

Answer (score 0):

```
  (your appium path) /AppiumSetup/appium/tutorial/projects/java_ios/>  mvn -Dtest=appium.tutorial.ios.YourAppNameTestCases clean test

/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js --address 127.0.0.1 --chromedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --selendroid-port 8082 --no-reset --local-timezone
```